# Запомнить ширину кнопки WinForms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

На панели создаются 3 кнопки

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Button button = new Button();
                button.Location = new Point(0 + i * 10, 280 - i * 20);
                button.Name = "but" + i;
                button.Height = 20; 
                button.Width = 120 - i*20; 
                button.Click += Button_Click;
                panel1.Controls.Add(button);
            }
```

При клике на созданную кнопку нужно записать в переменную ее ширину, чтобы воспроизвести (создать заново) в другом месте на панели

Нашел конструкцию для вывода на экран названия кнопки и ее удаления, но не знаю как запомнить ширину

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(((Button)sender).Name);
            this.panel1.Controls.Remove(sender as Button);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо ввести приватную переменную, в которой будет храниться ширина:

```
private int _buttonWidth;
```

В методе обработки события надо добавить сохранение ширины. На самом деле в нем есть несколько присущих новичку ошибок, поэтому приведу другой вариант:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;

    if (button == null)
        return;

    MessageBox.Show(button.Name);
    panel1.Controls.Remove(button);

    _buttonWidth = button.Width;
}
```